# Spring security introspection not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, wso2, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to implement opaque token validation for my resource server, which runs on Spring Boot 2.4.5 with the dependencies `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` and `oauth2-oidc-sdk`, and I am struggling to make the call to the introspection endpoint work.

The authorization server is WSO2 Identity Server.

Here's my code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaquetoken.introspection-uri}")
    String introspectionUri;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaquetoken.client-id}")
    String clientId;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaquetoken.client-secret}")
    String clientSecret;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                    .opaqueToken(opaque -> opaque
                        .introspectionUri(this.introspectionUri)
                        .introspectionClientCredentials(this.clientId, this.clientSecret)
                    )
            );
    }

}
```

In the `application.properties` I've got:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaquetoken.introspection-uri=https://localhost:9443/oauth2/introspect
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaquetoken.client-id=admin
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaquetoken.client-secret=admin
```

The backend replies to all requests with `401`, and it doesn't seem to even contact the authorization server. I read the documentation and watched plenty of examples, but can't figure out what's wrong. Could you help me please?

I also would like to know if the use of the introspection endpoint is correct and if it's the only way a resource server has to validate a non-JWT token.

**Edit**: @jzheaux: I was using `DEBUG` logging, now with `TRACE` I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: I/O error on POST request for "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/introspect": PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.OpaqueTokenAuthenticationProvider.getOAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal(OpaqueTokenAuthenticationProvider.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.OpaqueTokenAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OpaqueTokenAuthenticationProvider.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

It seems like a certification problem, but with Postman WSO2's introspection endpoint works flawlessly.

These are the response headers as shown by Postman (body is empty):

[image]

Comment: Please include the full 401 response, including headers. Please use TRACE logging for org.springframework.security and paste the logs emitted for the failing request.

Comment: seems like related to ssl/cert, does it work if you try to run `http://localhost:9443/oauth2/introspect` as http only instead? like `http://localhost:8080/oauth2/introspect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the WSO2 Identity Server's certificate. You need to import the it into java's *cacerts* file (inside lib/security).

Comment: Thank you, I tried importing into the cacerts file a certificate called "wso2carbon", which was in the wso2carbon keystore, but it didn't work. Then I finally found out that I had to create a public certificate from the whole keystore, as explained here: https://nadeesha678.wordpress.com/2015/09/21/adding-wso2-public-certificate-to-java-certificate-store/. Now it works.